# Low-byte fuse programming of ATmega328 on Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino-uno, atmega328, oscillator-clock

I want to use the ATmega328 on my Arduino Uno board to clock a [TDC1000](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tdc1000.pdf) using the clkout bit of the ATmega328, but this requires fuse programming of the low byte. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: Get a programmer and use avrdude.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have another Arduino? If so, check [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tzGLoqvSJdw&t=194s&pp=ygUJYXZyZHVkZXNz) and you can set the fuses with AVRDUDESS.

Be careful: if you set the fuses the wrong way you kind of "brick" the chip, and depending on the mess, you can only recover with a high voltage programmer.

One advantage is that you can never ruin the chip with the fuses, just make it hard to reset to some defaults.